# Filter a dictionary of lists

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary of the form:

```
{"level": [1, 2, 3],
 "conf": [-1, 1, 2],
 "text": ["here", "hel", "llo"]}
```

I want to filter the lists to remove every item at index `i` where an index in the value `"conf"` is not >0.

So for the above `dict`, the output should be this:

```
{"level": [2, 3],
 "conf": [1, 2],
 "text": ["hel", "llo"]}
```

As the first value of `conf` was not > 0.

I have tried something like this:

```
new_dict = {i: [a for a in j if a >= min_conf] for i, j in my_dict.items()}
```

But that would work just for one key.

Comment: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/absolute_beginners.html#whats-the-difference-between-a-python-list-and-a-numpy-array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved it with this:

```
from typing import Dict, List, Any, Set

d = {"level":[1,2,3], "conf":[-1,1,2], "text":["-1", "hel", "llo"]}

# First, we create a set that stores the indices which should be kept.
# I chose a set instead of a list because it has a O(1) lookup time.
# We only want to keep the items on indices where the value in d["conf"] is greater than 0
filtered_indexes = {i for i, value in enumerate(d.get('conf', [])) if value > 0}

def filter_dictionary(d: Dict[str, List[Any]], filtered_indexes: Set[int]) -> Dict[str, List[Any]]:
    filtered_dictionary = d.copy()  # We'll return a modified copy of the original dictionary
    for key, list_values in d.items():
        # In the next line the actual filtering for each key/value pair takes place. 
        # The original lists get overwritten with the filtered lists.
        filtered_dictionary[key] = [value for i, value in enumerate(list_values) if i in filtered_indexes]
    return filtered_dictionary

print(filter_dictionary(d, filtered_indexes))
```

Output:

```
{'level': [2, 3], 'conf': [1, 2], 'text': ['hel', 'llo']}
```

Answer (score 15):

try:

```py
from operator import itemgetter


def filter_dictionary(d):
    positive_indices = [i for i, item in enumerate(d['conf']) if item > 0]
    f = itemgetter(*positive_indices)
    return {k: list(f(v)) for k, v in d.items()}


d = {"level": [1, 2, 3], "conf": [-1, 1, 2], "text": ["-1", "hel", "llo"]}
print(filter_dictionary(d))
```

output:

```
{'level': [2, 3], 'conf': [1, 2], 'text': ['hel', 'llo']}
```

I tried to first see which indices of `'conf'` are positive, then with `itemgetter` I picked those indices from values inside the dictionary.

More compact version + without temporary list using generator expression instead:

```py
def filter_dictionary(d):
    f = itemgetter(*(i for i, item in enumerate(d['conf']) if item > 0))
    return {k: list(f(v)) for k, v in d.items()}
```

Answer (score 11):

Here's a one-liner:

```
dct = {k: [x for i, x in enumerate(v) if d['conf'][i] > 0] for k, v in d.items()}
```

Output:

```
>>> dct
{'level': [2, 3], 'conf': [1, 2], 'text': ['hel', 'llo']}
```

With sample data:

```
d = {"level":[1,2,3], "conf":[-1,1,2], "text":["here","hel","llo"]
```

Answer (score 10):

I would keep the indexes of valid elements (those greater than 0) with:

```
kept_keys = [i for i in range(len(my_dict['conf'])) if my_dict['conf'][i] > 0]
```

And then you can filter each list checking if the index of a certain element in the list is contained in `kept_keys`:

```
{k: list(map(lambda x: x[1], filter(lambda x: x[0] in kept_keys, enumerate(my_dict[k])))) for k in my_dict}
```

Output:

```
{'level': [2, 3], 'conf': [1, 2], 'text': ['hel', 'llo']}
```

Answer (score 5):

The structure of the data you're describing sounds like it might be more naturally modelled as a [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/overview.html) DataFrame: you are essentially viewing your data as a 2-D grid, and you want to filter out rows of that grid based on the value in one column.

The following snippet will do what you need using a DataFrame as an intermediate representation:

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {"level":[1,2,3], "conf":[-1,1,2], "text":["here","hel","llo"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df = df.loc[df["conf"] > 0]
result = df.to_dict(orient="list")
```

Output:

```py
{'level': [2, 3], 'conf': [1, 2], 'text': ['hel', 'llo']}
```

However, note that if you represent your data as a DataFrame in the first place, and keep it in that form when you're done, this is simplified to,

```py
data = pd.DataFrame({
    "level":[1,2,3],
    "conf":[-1,1,2],
    "text":["here","hel","llo"],
})

result = data.loc[data["conf"] > 0]
```

Output:

```
   level  conf text
1      2     1  hel
2      3     2  llo
```

Which is terser, more expressive, and (on large inputs) more performant than any "pure dict" solution.

If the other operations you want to do on this data are similar (in the sense of really being '2D array' operations), it is likely that they will also be more naturally expressed in terms of DataFrames, and so keeping your data as a DataFrame is likely  to be advantageous vs converting back to a dict.

Comment: Maybe this is a minor thing, but *"represent your data as a DataFrame in the first place"* seems like a red herring. Inlining the data into the DataFrame call wouldn't make sense if it were, say, returned from a third-party function, or if it were very large. The important thing is putting the data into a df, regardless of how it gets there.

Answer (score 3):

Try this, simple and easy to understand, especially for beginners:

```
a_dict = {"level": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8], "conf": [-1, 1, -1, -2], "text": ["-1", "hel", "llo", "ai", 0, 9]}

# iterate backwards over the list keeping the indexes
for index, item in reversed(list(enumerate(a_dict["conf"]))):
    if item <= 0:
        for lists in a_dict.values():
            del lists[index]
print(a_dict)
```

Output:

```
{'level': [2, 5, 8], 'conf': [1], 'text': ['hel', 0, 9]}
```

Comment: Nice, this is smart! Other answers build up the list of indexes first, but it's simpler to pick them out one-by-one. Probably less performant though, but easier to understand.

Answer (score 3):

```
a = {"level":[1,2,3,4], "conf": [-1,1,2,-1],"text": ["-1","hel","llo","test"]}

# inefficient solution
# for k, v in a.items():
#     if k == "conf":
#         start_search = 0
#         to_delete = [] #it will store the index numbers of the conf that you want to delete(conf<0)
#         for element in v:
#             if element < 0:
#                 to_delete.append(v.index(element,start_search))
#                 start_search = v.index(element) + 1

#more efficient and elegant solution
to_delete = [i for i, element in enumerate(a["conf"]) if element < 0]
for position in list(reversed(to_delete)):
    for k, v in a.items():
        v.pop(position)
```

and the result will be

```
>>> a
{'level': [2, 3], 'conf': [1, 2], 'text': ['hel', 'llo']}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can have a function which works out which indexes to keep and reformulate each list with only those indexes:

```py
my_dict = {"level":[1,2,3], "conf":[-1,1,2],'text':["-1","hel","llo"]}

def remove_corresponding_items(d, key):
    keep_indexes = [idx for idx, value in enumerate(d[key]) if value>0]
    for key, lst in d.items():
        d[key] = [lst[idx] for idx in keep_indexes]

remove_corresponding_items(my_dict, 'conf')
print(my_dict)
```

Output as requested

Answer (score 3):

Lots of good answers. Here's another 2-pass approach:

```
mydict = {"level": [1, 2, 3], "conf": [-1, 1, 2], 'text': ["-1", "hel", "llo"]}

for i, v in enumerate(mydict['conf']):
    if v <= 0:
        for key in mydict.keys():
            mydict[key][i] = None

for key in mydict.keys():
    mydict[key] = [v for v in mydict[key] if v is not None]

print(mydict)
```

**Output:**

```
{'level': [2, 3], 'conf': [1, 2], 'text': ['hel', 'llo']}
```

Comment: It'd help to add an explanation of how this code works. Just a sentence or two would be fine, like "get the index of each negative `conf` value, set it to `None` across the whole dict, then filter them out."

Answer (score 3):

Here's a numpy way of doing it:

```
dct = {"level":[1,2,3], "conf":[-1,1,2], "text":["here","hel","llo"]}
dct = {k: np.array(v) for k, v in d.items()}
dct = {k: v[a['conf'] > 0].tolist() for k, v in a.items()}
```

Output:

```
>>> dct
{'level': [2, 3], 'conf': [1, 2], 'text': ['hel', 'llo']}
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe this will work:
For each list, we will filter the values where `conf` is negative, and after that we will filter `conf` itself.

```py
d = {"level":[1,2,3], "conf":[-1,1,2], "text":["-1","hel","llo"]}
for key in d:
    if key != "conf":
        d[key] = [d[key][i] for i in range(len(d[key])) if d["conf"][i] >= 0]
d["conf"] = [i for i in d["conf"] if i>=0]
print(d)
```

A simpler solution will be (exactly the same but using list comprehension, so we don't need to do it separately for `conf` and the rest:

```py
d = {"level":[1,2,3], "conf":[-1,1,2], "text":["-1","hel","llo"]}

d = {i:[d[i][j] for j in range(len(d[i])) if d["conf"][j] >= 0] for i in d}
```

Output:
`{'level': [2, 3], 'conf': [1, 2], 'text': ['hel', 'llo']}`

Comment: Simpler: `d[key] = [v for i,v in enumerate(d[key]) if d["conf"][i] >= 0]`